# Se pueden usara las variables de una clase como tipo?

Tags: c#, mvc, razor

Quiero utilizar una variable como tipo, algo así:

```
    public class ComponentTablaModel<T> where T : class, new()
    {
        public T Clase { get; set; }
        public List<string> Titles { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class fakeClass
    {
        public string DniCliente { get; set; }
        public int EASYCODE { get; set; }
        public double Telefono { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaRegistro { get; set; }
        public decimal DecimalCC { get; set; }
        public DateTime CT_FECHA_CARGA { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    @model webS.Models.ComponentTablaModel<T>
    public void Test()
    {
      List<Model.Clase> testData = GetSql(sql);
    }
```

quiero hacer algo así o que pueda utilizar cualquier tipo de clase en public void test, es para crea  un componente tabla en c# que se pueda reutilizar por cualquier clase y llamarlo con un partial ya que uso MVC razor

Comment: `List<T> testData = GetSql(sql);` ???????

Comment: No funciona ya que al  usar T no guarda bien los datos